# Is it possible to use Django's SafeExceptionReporterFilter with something else than the AdminEmailHandler?

Tags: python, django, logging, filter, error-logging

I'm trying to filter out sensitive informations using Django's `@sensitive_post_parameters`. I thought prepending these annotations over a the few specific fonctions would be enough, but it doesn't work. I've set breakpoint inside `SafeExceptionReporterFilter` and  it only breaks when being called from the `AdminEmailHandler` and **not** the other handlers. What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you set `DEBUG=False` ?

Comment: Yes obviously, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use the `SafeExceptionReporterFilter`, exceptions will still contains sensitive data (e.g. your Server's ENV variables and other runtime data).

To avoid exposing sensitive data, you should not use this filter. Instead, write your own Exception Handler Middleware and selectively(recursively?) fetch yourself the data you want in the logs.

See [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples) on how to obtain exception's traceback and how to use it for your needs.

Even if you go with a CustomHandler you'll be limited with a specific handler and as far as I know, third-parties handlers won't use the `SafeExceptionReporterFilter`.

Comment: Indeed, I did try to create a custom handler as @aumo suggested me, but it was based on the graypy GELF handler and it was not possible to add the filtering without rewriting the whole thing. As for the sensitive runtime data, I know the security guy won't let me log them. I think I'll go ahead and write my own exception logger middleware as it's the only way I can control how the information is disclosed. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom [Handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects) that uses `django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter` to format the exception.

Example use of `ExceptionReporter`:

```
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter

# exc_type, exc_value, traceback are a standard exception
# tuple as returned by sys.exc_info
reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
html_report = reporter.get_traceback_html()
text_report = reporter.get_traceback_text()
```

`ExceptionReporter` will use the `ExceptionReporterFilter` defined by the `DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER` setting  which by default is `SafeExceptionReporterFilter`.

Have a look at `AdminEmailHandler`'s [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django%2Futils%2Flog.py#L89) to get info on how to create a custom `Handler`.